# Formatting a GroupBy result for Report

Tags: c#, performance, linq, knockout.js

I've been struggling with this a couple of days. I've created a report to measure visits made to customers by employees (a.k.a. Visits KPI).

The report is actually working, but loading times are around 10 seconds, something i've managed to solve using GroupBy statements instead my regular creation of Lists, queries, query again, another set of lists and serialize to JSON.

What i need to do is very "simple". I'm querying a Month of a certain year (e.g.: August, 2014), but i need to retreive information from 2 months before that, using the example, i need data from August 2014, July 2014 and June 2014. One column shows information for August, the second for July and so on. Using GroupBy i've managed to get this so the results are something like this:

1. User 1

   - August

     - Reported Visits: 3
     - UnReported Visits: 2
   - July

     - Reported Visits: 5
     - UnReported Visits: 3
   - June

     - Reported Visits: 1
     - UnReported Visits: 6
2. User 2

   - August

     - Reported Visits: 3
     - UnReported Visits: 2
   - June

     - Reported Visits: 1
     - UnReported Visits: 6

And so on...

Well, i'm OK here BUT i need to always retrieve 3 PERIODS, with this result for example USER 2 doesn't have information for July beacuse he didn't make any visits that month. The thing is that i need that results for JULY column to be all zero to fit my table/column layout (in HTML). Something like this:

1. User 1

   - August

     - Reported Visits: 3
     - UnReported Visits: 2
   - July

     - Reported Visits: 5
     - UnReported Visits: 3
   - June

     - Reported Visits: 1
     - UnReported Visits: 6
2. User 2

   - August

     - Reported Visits: 3
     - UnReported Visits: 2
   - **July**

     - **Reported Visits: 0**
     - **UnReported Visits: 0**
   - June

     - Reported Visits: 1
     - UnReported Visits: 6

The LINQ statement i'm using:

```
var visitasGrouped = from visit in visits
                     group visit by visit.Author into visitsAuthor
                     orderby visitsAuthor.Key ascending
                     from visitsGroup in
                         (from visit in visitsAuthor
                          group visit by visit.DateScheduled.Month)
                     group visitsGroup by visitsAuthor.Key;
```

Obviously the count() parts are calculated inside foreach statements.

Any help would be appreciated, including improving the LINQ statement, any C#/LINQ sorcery, format the received JSON array with Knockout or jQuery. EVERYTHING.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: My linq is not great, but I can give you a tip: you want to select from a collection of months, instead of relying on the grouped visits for the month. You will then need a subquery to selects visits for each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this without a compiler or any testing, but this should get you on the right path:

```
var months = Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
    .Select(x => endDate.AddMonths(-1*x).Month))
    .ToList();

var results = visits
    .GroupBy(v => v.Author)
        .SelectMany(v => months
            .Select(m =>
                new {
                    author = v.Key,
                    month = m,
                    reportedVisits = v.Count(v => v.Reported && v.DateScheduled.Month = m),
                    unreportedVisits = v.Count(v => v.Unreported && v.DateScheduled.Month = m),
                });
```

Note that this could be inefficient if visits is a large dataset, and I don't know if this will translate into SQL happily. Like I said, my LINQ is not great. But it shows you the principal: those months are not going to come from nowhere, you will need to specify them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL, join to a set of months that gives you a predictable base result for each user, as the other answer says.  If you'd rather transform the output after you get it, javascript and knockout should be pretty easy to work with here:

```
// assuming your data looks like:
var data = {
    user1: { august: 10, july: 4 },
    user2: { august: 8, june: 3 }
};

// then generate some set of defaults like:
var defaults = { august: 0, july: 0, june: 0 };

// and do this to normalize each user:
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).map(function (user) {
    // assuming jquery, but replace with any object copying logic otherwise
    return $.extend({}, defaults, data[user]);
});
```